# How can I run a function when a course module is deleted in moodle?

Tags: php, plugins, moodle

I want to run a function when this button is clicked and the course module is deleted.

How can I do this?

[image: whatIwant]

In db/events.php:

```
$observers = array(

    array(
        'eventname'   => '\core\event\course_module_deleted',
        'callback'    => 'mod_game_observer::course_module_deleted',
    ),
);
```

In classes/observer.php:

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();


class mod_game_observer {

    /**
     * Observer for the even course_module_deleted.
     *
     * @param \core\event\course_module_deleted $event
     */
    public static function course_module_deleted(\core\event\course_module_deleted $event) {
        global $DB;
        //die(var_dump($event));
        $DB->delete_records_select("game_results", "cmid = ".$event->objectid);
        $DB->delete_records_select("game", "id = ".$event->other['instanceid']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its better to ask this question in Moodle forum https://moodle.org/mod/forum/index.php?id=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Moodle Events API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API) documentation; it details Moodle's framework for logging events, for observing/listening for events, and for triggering callback functions when an event occurs.

The docs also include a list of core/standard events, and the Events API is extendable if you need to create a custom event specific to your need.

One of the existing/core events sounds relevant to your need: core\event\course_module_deleted

Here are a few common steps for leveraging the events framework to reach your goal:

- Determine the core/standard event that is relevant to your need, or create a new event if nothing fits perfectly
- Understand what data is logged with the event so you can filter/target events that are relevant to the course/course module/scenario/etc. where you want to take action.

  - One way to do this is searching existing core code or plugins for examples of where the event is logged
  - Alternately, if you have an existing Moodle site, you can visit Site Admin -> Reports -> Events list and look at detail related to the event (e.g. eventlist/eventdetail.php?eventname=%5Ccore%5Cevent%5Ccourse_module_deleted)
  - You can also look at the data being stored in the DB for the event, in Moodle's logstore table
- Inside a plugin, create a Moodle observer function that listens for the event you  need; these observers are designed to trigger a callback function, and the callback function can contain the code you want to execute when the event occurs

  - Using the example event mentioned above, you'd setup an observer for the core\event\course_module_deleted event.
  - Be sure the event you are going to observe/listen for is logged at the time/location in the code where you need your callback function to be executed; if not, you may need to create a custom event that can be logged in the right location/at the right time. In your case, for example, if you need your callback to execute immediately after the user chooses "Delete", but the core event is logged farther into the delete cycle, you may want to create a custom event and have it logged right at the start of the code that executes when Delete is selected.
- Follow Moodle's framework for creating a plugin and adding observers to a plugin. This enables an observer to be registered properly so that the observer and any callback functions associated with the observer will execute properly.

Hope this is helpful - good luck!

Comment: I've created the observers and the callback function. I bumped up the plugin version and purged caches, also confirmed that my plugin is observing the event in 'Events List' but the function doesn't run. Did I miss something? I've edited my question to include the code I added.

Comment: I've tried \core\event\course_module_updated which works but \core\event\course_module_deleted doesn't why is that?

Comment: Nevermind, I just learned there is a recycle bin in moodle.